# Exchangeability of random vector

Tags: exchange, random-variables

I hope you can help me with this rather basic question that I asked myself. A random vector $(X_1,...,X_n)$ is said to be exchangeable if it has the same distribution as the permuted random vector $(X_{\pi(1)},...,X_{\pi(d)})$, for any permutation $(\pi{(1)},...\pi{(d)})$.

Can you say that this is the case if and only if the covariance matrix of the random vector $(X_1,...,X_n)$ is symmetric (edit: diagonal not symmetric)? Or is that not sufficient? I can't think of a counter example...

Thanks already, any hints are very much appreciated! :-)

Comment: (The true) covariance matrix is always symmetric, it is not a restriction.

Comment: Perhaps you meant : if the random vector is exchangeable then the covariance matrix is diagonal. (but not the converse).

Comment: In what applications or models in finance do we permutate financial data while retaining its original distribution? What purpose does this serve

Comment: @develarist: for example the increments of a random walk (which is ubiquitous in Finance as a simple model of an efficent market) are exchangeable.

Comment: Probably the de finetti’s theorem is the answer to your question: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Finetti%27s_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Wombat: I think it's best to think of it this way. Suppose you have a time series and the joint distribution of $n$ elements ( in a certain, specific order) of the series is normal with mean zero and some non-diagonal covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

Then, in this case, exchangeability means that you could take the $n$ elements in any order and the joint distribution of the $n$ elements stays the same.  Note that the explanation below would only be true for the normal assumption case. In non-normal cases, maybe symmetric is needed. I don't know.

Anyway, getting back to the normal case, you would have a stronger condition than symmetry. Basically, you'll need all of the elements of the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ to be interchangeable without effecting the distribution. This implies a constant covariance value in each element of the matrix. That's stronger than symmetry because different lags have the same covariance.

Comment: Note that noob2's comment of a diagonal matrix is a special case ( where the elements are all zero )  of what I wrote above so correct also.

Comment: Wombat: I just realized that, if you're instructor has talked about "white noise", then maybe noob2's answer is more correct. Hopefully you get the general idea but it could be that your instructor is trying to give a feel for what "white noise" is in which case you need zeros.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers. I meant diagonal not symmetric, sorry. I don't know, why I wrote symmetric... I was probably a bit tired. But noob2 answered my question, diagonal is not sufficient.

Comment: But diagonal is sufficient if all the elements along the diagonal are the same.

Answer (score 1):

let's take X1=1 and X2=2:

The covariance matrix is zero (X1 and X2 are independents) and X1, X2 have different distributions!!!